# Find query matches within a string

Tags: javascript, regex, autocomplete

I have a task to calculate characters to highlight in the text based on a query.
Let's say the given text is `"London, United Kingdom"` and query is `"lond"`. Then the result should be `[[0, 4]]`.

I have a simple implementation which works fine for this case:

```
// ...
.reduce((result, word) => {
  const wordLen = word.length;
  const prefix = wordCharacterRegex.test(word[0]) ? "\\b" : "";
  const regex = new RegExp(prefix + escapeRegexCharacters(word), "i");
  const index = text.search(regex);

  if (index > -1) {
    result.push([index, index + wordLen]);

    text =
      text.slice(0, index) +
      new Array(wordLen + 1).join(" ") +
      text.slice(index + wordLen);
  }

  return result;
}, [])
// ...
```

but then if text is `"EC2V 6DB, London, United Kingdom"` and the query is `"ec2v6db"` it doesn't work because the regular expression will be `/\bec2v6db/i`. 
So, how can I change my code and fix the problem?

Comment: well not sure how you expect it to match the whitespace...

Comment: Is the query a string literal or a regular expression? If it's literal and you want to accept whitespace in the middle if the patterns, you could insert `\s*` between each character of the word, while making sure to escape special characters in the query.

Comment: Hi @joanis it is a string, so I can try to insert `\s*` between each character

Comment: Then indeed, `/\be\s*c\s*2\s*v\s*6\s*d\s*b\s*/i` should work for your specific example, if it fits your requirements. I noticed you put `\b` at the beginning: did you intend to demand the match be at the beginning of a word?

Comment: @joanis that's right! I need to match only at the beginning of a word, because I write this script for autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the word boundary you add if the first char is a word char should probably be consistent with regards to non-word chars: if you add `\b` before word chars, add `\B` before non-word chars to get the same behavior.

```
const prefix = wordCharacterRegex.test(word[0]) ? "\\b" : "\\B";
```

Then, it is not clear what your `escapeRegexCharacters` method looks like but it is there where you may insert `\s*` between each char of the keyword:

```
function escapeRegexCharacters(s) {
    var res = s.replace(/([-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])|[\s\S]/g, (m,g) => (g ? "\\" + g : m) + "\\s*");
    return res.substring(0, res.length -3);
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
let word = "ec2v6db"; // lond is checked
let text = "EC2V 6DB, London, United Kingdom";
const wordCharacterRegex = /\w/;

function escapeRegexCharacters(s) {
    var res = s.replace(/([-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])|[\s\S]/g, (m,g) => (g ? "\\" + g : m) + "\\s*");
    return res.substring(0, res.length -3);
}

const prefix = wordCharacterRegex.test(word[0]) ? "\\b" : "\\B";
const regex = new RegExp(prefix + escapeRegexCharacters(word), "i");

// Replacing text with spaces
console.log(text.replace(regex, m => " ".repeat(m.length)));
// => "        , London, United Kingdom"

// Adding tags around the match
console.log(text.replace(regex, "<highlight>$&</highlight>"));

// Getting the indices:
let match = regex.exec(text);
if (match) {
   console.log([match.index, match.index+match[0].length]);
}
```

Comment: I am afraid it's not gonna work for `EC2V 6DB, London, United Kingdom` when  query is `ec2v6db`

Comment: @rel1x See the updated demo with the `ec2v6db` query and `EC2V 6DB, London, United Kingdom` input. Output is `[[0,7]]`. As expected.

Comment: i am pretty sure it should be `[[0, 8]]`, otherwise from 0 to 7 would match `EC2V 6D` only and forgot about `B`

Comment: @rel1x See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1aW0KC/1), the regex is fine. The issue is that you have `wordLen` set to the length of the original search word and not of the match. I think your code is somewhat redundant. Do you need to just replace each match char with space?

Comment: yes, the regex itself is fine! Thank you, I will update my script and make sure it returns [0, 8]

Comment: @rel1x Please check the current code, I think it should work as expected now. Each match is now replaced with the same amount of spaces thanks to `" ".repeat(m.length)` and I also added a `replace` code showing how to wrap the match with a tag. And indices, too.